# How to properly use quotes for a bash function?

Tags: bash, quoting

I am trying to define the following bash function in my `.bashrc` file:

```
function myfind() {
    find $1 -not -path venv -not -path .tox -name "$2" | xargs grep -n "$3"
}
```

which is not doing what I expect. When I use that function to search for text in files, e.g.

```
myfind . *.py test
```

it does not return anything. But when I use the expression directly, i.e.

```
find . -not -path venv -not -path .tox -name "*.py" | xargs grep -n "test"
```

it returns some matches.

I already tried to use double quotes like

```
function myfind() {
    find $1 -not -path venv -not -path .tox -name '"$2"' | xargs grep -n '"$3"'
}
```

or

```
function myfind() {
    find $1 -not -path venv -not -path .tox -name "'$2'" | xargs grep -n "'$3'"
}
```

and tried to escape the quotes like

```
function myfind() {
    find $1 -not -path venv -not -path .tox -name \"$2\" | xargs grep -n \"$3\"
}
```

but none of these seem to be working.

How to fix this bash function so the quotes are being "used" around the arguments?

Comment: What about calling it by `myfind . "*.py" test`?

Comment: Yes that works as well...

Comment: It's a good practice to always quote globbed names for `find`to keep the shell from expanding it. The same applies to your find-script. You can't solve that problem inside the script because the damage is already done before the script gets to see the parameter.

Comment: Btw.: See `help function` for correct syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ITYM:

```
myfind() {
  find "$1" '(' -name venv -o -name .tox ')' -prune -o \
            -name "$2" -type f -exec grep -Hne "$3" -- {} +
}
```

And then:

```
myfind . '*.py' test
```

See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) for why calling `xargs` on the output of `find` like that is wrong.

Some other problems with your approach:

- `-path venv` would never match anything as `-path` matches on the full path of the file being considered which will be something like `<contents-of-$1>/subdir/file`. Only at the top level of the invocation of `myfind venv ...` would it ever match. I assume you want to ignore files stored under directories called `venv`. While you could use `! -path '*/venv/*'` for that, telling `find` not to descend into those directories in the first place is more efficient than filter out all  the files in there after the fact (`! -path '*/venv/*'` is also problematic if there are file paths that are not valid text in the locale).
- with `myfind first *.py last`, you're asking the shell to expand `*.py` into the list of matching files in the current directory to make up the second to second-last arguments to `myfind`, while it's a literal `*.py` argument you want to pass to `myfind` for `myfind` to pass it along to `find` after `-name`, hence the need to quote the `*` character so it's not interpreted as a globbing operator by the shell. Here, we're quoting the whole `*.py` with `'*.py'` though `'*'.py` or `\*.py` would be enough as the other 3 characters (`.`, `p` and `y`) are not special to the shell.

  if using zsh instead of bash, you'd be able to do `alias myfind='noglob myfind'` for globbing to be disabled in arguments to `myfind`. Then you'd be able to do `myfind . *.py test` without that `*.py` being expanded by the shell.
- parameter expansions must be quoted to prevent split+glob  (`"$1"`, not `$1`).
- Without `-H` (a GNU extension) if `find` finds only one file, `grep` wouldn't print its path, so you wouldn't know where the matches are. With `grep` implementations that don't support `-H`, you can pass `/dev/null` as an extra argument: `-exec grep -ne "$3" -- /dev/null {} +`.
- See `!` for the standard (and shorter) equivalent to the non-standard `-not`.
- with `grep -n "$3"`, if `$3` started with `-`, it would be taken as an option by `grep`. Hence the `-e "$3"` instead where the contents of `$3` is passed as an argument to the `-e` option. There is the same problem with `find "$1"`, however unfortunately, there is not standard workaround for that. `find -- "$1"` would stop the contents of `$1` from being treated as an *option* by `find` it started with `-`, but it would still be treated as a *predicate*, so it's pointless. A directory called `!` or `(` for instance would also be a problem.  BSD `find` have `find -f "$1"` for that, but GNU `find` and most other `find` implementations don't support it. Use `myfind ./-dir-starting-with-data- '*.py' pattern` to pass a directory starting with dash.
- the only thing that is not standard `sh` syntax in your code is that `function name()` function definition syntax. The ksh syntax is `function name {...;}`, the Bourne and standard and `bash` syntax is `name() {...;}`. While `bash` also supports `function name() { ...; }` by accident, there's no really good reason to use it.
- I've added a `-type f` to only considered *regular* files as you likely don't want `grep`  to start search inside device files or fifos and it would report errors for directories or sockets. With GNU `find`, you can replace it with `-xtype f` so that symlinks eventually resolving to regular files be also considered.

Comment: *While bash also supports `function name() { ...; }`*. Could it be that you meant `function name { ...; }` without the parenthesis?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: Why would you think so?  (1) Like [the March Hare](https://www.alice-in-wonderland.net/resources/chapters-script/alice-in-wonderland-quotes/), Stéphane usually says what he means and means what he says. (2) There are two standard-ish syntaxes for declaring shell functions: *`name`* + `()` and `function` + *`name`*.  The OP used the hybrid syntax `function` + *`name`* + `()` in the question, and Stéphane is pointing out that, while this works in bash, it’s non-standard and non-portable.

Comment: @Scott You are right, I misunderstood the paragraph. I know Stéphane's excellence in every answer and comment, it's invaluable.